# Returning empty queryset when using djongo with django-rest-framework

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework, djongo

I have some pre-defined collections in mongodb having some data and now I am using django-rest-framework to make apis with the existing mongodb collection. So, I have designed models same as my existing schema in mongodb and using **djongo.models**.

```
from djongo import models

class HsnMasters(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    pro_code = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
    description = models.TextField()
    gst = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
    hsn_code = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    deactivate = models.IntegerField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    objects = models.DjongoManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "product_master"
```

My views code -:

```
class TaxDirectory(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        print(HsnMasters.objects.all())
        return super().get_queryset()
    queryset = HsnMasters.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HsnMasterSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

But over here I am getting empty collection. Any idea why I am getting a empty queryset.

Comment: Did you try any query on `python manage.py shell` by `import`ing your model whether the data is coming from database or not ?

Comment: Yes I have tried this too, but there in the shell its giving me a empty queryset.  But if I am using              
** from lib.db.mongo_helper import Document ** to get the document so data is fetched properly from mongodb.